# Adding uBlock Origin block list subscriptions from CLI?

Tags: bash, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, ublock-origin

### Context

While trying to automatically configure uBlock Origin, I am experiencing some difficulties in determining how to add a block list automatically. [This link](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Filter-lists-from-around-the-web) explains how one can manually subscribe to a list with uBlock filters.

### Approach I

So I tried to manually add this list:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quenhus/uBlock-Origin-dev-filter/main/data/stackoverflow_copycats.txt

and see where the string `copycats` is found in my pc, however I did not find it.

### Approach II

From manually browsing, I found some block lists seem to be stored in: `~/mozilla/firefox/extensions/assets/ublock/`.

However adding the blocklist as:
`~/mozilla/firefox/extensions/assets/ublock/stackoverflow_copycats.txt`
with content:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quenhus/uBlock-Origin-dev-filter/main/data/stackoverflow_copycats.txt
```

Did not result in uBlock adding the custom list in: moz-extension://c12c7594-a289-4459-a7ff-71d72f46dacf/dashboard.html#3p-filters.html

### Approach III

Adding the blocklist as:
`~/mozilla/firefox/extensions/assets/ublock/stackoverflow_copycats.txt`
with (the content from the GitHub file):

```
! Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arosh/ublacklist-stackoverflow-translation/master/uBlacklist.txt
! Stackoverflow copycats
*://code-examples.net/*
*://kotaeta.com/*
*://answer-id.com/*
*://code.i-harness.com/*
*://living-sun.com/*
*://qastack.jp/*
*://qastack.ru/*
*://qastack.it/*
*://qastack.mx/*
*://qastack.com.br/*
*://qastack.info.tr/*
*://qastack.in.th/*
*://qastack.com.de/*
*://qastack.fr/*
*://qastack.cn/*
*://qastack.com.ua/*
*://qastack.co.in/*
*://qastack.kr/*
*://qastack.vn/*
*://qastack.net.bd/*
*://qa-stack.pl/*
*://qastack.id/*
*://coder.work/*
*://it-swarm-ja.tech/*
*://it-swarm.jp.net/*
*://it-mure.jp.net/*
*://it-swarm-ja.com/*
*://it-swarm.com.ru/*
*://it-swarm-fr.com/*
*://codeflow.site/*
*://codeguides.site/*
*://overcoder.net/*
*://coderoad.ru/*
*://generacodice.blog/*
*://generacodice.it/*
*://generacodice.com/*
*://javaer101.com/*
*://voidcc.com/*
*://siwib.org/*
*://fluffyfables.com/*
*://fixes.pub/*
*://knews.vip/*
*://isolution.pro/*
*://uwenku.com/*
*://lycaeum.dev/*
*://brocante.dev/*
*://classmethod.dev/*
*://stormcrow.dev/*
*://athabasca-foto.com/*
*://zsharp.org/*
*://projectbackpack.org/*
*://waymanamechurch.org/*
*://sunflowercreations.org/*
*://cfadnc.org/*
*://fitforlearning.org/*
*://panaindustrial.com/*
*://sierrasummit2005.org/*
*://theshuggahpies.com/*
*://pcbconline.org/*
*://nuomiphp.com/*
*://ubuntu.buildwebhost.com/*
*://ubuntuaa.com/*
*://debugcn.com/*
*://sch22.org/*
*://gupgallery.com/*
*://amuddycup.com/*
*://ecnf2016.org/*
*://softwareuser.asklobster.com/*
*://domainelespailles.net/*
*://ec-europe.org/*
*://pakostnici.com/*
*://try2explore.com/*
*://laravelquestions.com/*
*://itectec.com/*
*://stackovergo.com/*
*://faithcov.org/*
*://noblenaz.org/*
*://py4u.net/*
*://culinarydegree.info/*
*://safehavenpetrescue.org/*
*://qapicks.com/*
*://issues-world.com/*
*://narkive.jp/*
*://ourladylakes.org/*
*://intellipaat.com/*
*://article.docway.net/*
*://xiu2.net/*
*://codehero.jp/*
*://quabr.com/*
*://webdevqa.jp.net/*
*://exceptionshub.com/*
*://newbedev.com/*
*://codenong.com/*
*://cainiaojiaocheng.com/*
*://routinepanic.com/*
*://pythonwd.com/*
*://tutorialmore.com/*
*://alwaysemmyhope.com/*
*://pretagteam.com/*
*://titanwolf.org/*
*://coderedirect.com/*
*://ostack.cn/*
*://easysavecode.com/*
*://webdevdesigner.com/*
*://ghcc.net/*
*://developreference.com/*
*://semicolonworld.com/*
*://tipsfordev.com/*
*://qi-u.com/*
*://stackqna.com/*
*://xsprogram.com/*
*://stackoom.com/*
*://christfever.in/*
*://codersatellite.com/*
*://cndgn.com/*
*://coredump.biz/*
*://farath.com/*
*://devbugfix.com/*
*://tech.wayne-chu.com/*
*://stackify.dev/*
*://webknox.com/*
*://stackfinder.jp.net/*
*://coder-solution-jp.com/*
*://jpndev.com/*
*://uebu-kaihatsu.jp.net/*
*://sqlite.in/*
*://stackguides.com/*
*://younggeeks.in/*
*://answerlib.com/*
*://edupro.id/*
*://python-stack.de/*
*://stackfinder.ru/*
*://stackfault.net/*
*://howtofix.io/*
*://buzzphp.com/*
*://desenv-web-rp.com/*
*://askdev.vn/*
*://quares.ru/*
*://examplefiles.net/*
*://codewdw.com/*
*://jpcodeqa.com/*
*://tutorialguruji.com/*
*://justshowmethecode.com/*
*://it-roy-ru.com/*
*://jscodetips.com/*
*://5axxw.com/*
*://question-it.com/*
*://webmonkez.com/*
*://ibootweb.com/*
*://codefaq.info/*
*://codefaq.ru/*
*://mediatagtw.com/*
*://alltodev.com/*
*://progi.pro/*
*://jike.in/*
*://web-dev-qa.com/*
*://elfishgene.com/*
*://dapper-tutorial.net/*
*://cmsdk.com/*
*://ask-ubuntu.ru/*
*://askubuntu.ru/*
*://kompsekret.ru/*
*://ohandroid.com/*
*://poweruser.guru/*
*://ruphp.com/*
*://server-fault.ru/*
*://sprosi.pro/*
*://stackru.com/*
*://switch-case.ru/*
*://ubuntugeeks.com/*
*://ubuntuplace.info/*
*://wikiroot.ru/*
*://sysadminde.com/*
*://askdev.ru/*
*://qarchive.ru/*
*://qarus.ru/*
*://recalll.co/*
*://soinside.com/*
*://stackanswers.net/*
*://stackoverflood.com/*
*://switch-case.com/*
*://techarks.ru/*
*://techfeed.net/*
*://thinbug.com/*
*://utyatnishna.ru/*
*://v-resheno.ru/*
*://web-answers.ru/*
*://xszz.org/*
*://ylhow.com/*
*://yuanmacha.com/*
*://qa.1r1g.com/*
*://it-swarm.com.de/*
*://it-swarm-es.com/*
*://legkovopros.ru/*
*://mlink.in/*
*://mlog.club/*
*://overcoder.ru/*
*://prog-help.ru/*
*://qa-help.ru/*
*://devfaq.fr/*
*://extutorial.com/*
*://fooobar.com/*
*://husl.ru/*
*://answacode.com/*
*://answeright.com/*
*://codegear.dev/*
*://bilee.com/*
*://askvoprosy.com/*
*://de.askdev.info/*
*://codeindex.ru/*
*://codengineering.ru/*
*://coderoad.in/*
*://coderquestion.ru/*
*://dogovori.info/*
*://itecnote.com/*
*://askcodez.com/*
*://bootpanic.com/*
*://askentire.net/*
*://de-vraag.com/*
*://qacode.ru/*
*://sobrelinux.info/*
*://askfrance.me/*
*://respuestas.me/*
*://antwortenhier.me/*
*://proubuntu.ru/*
*://over.wiki/*
*://debiantutorials.org/*
*://grokbase.com/*
*://wp-qa.com/*
*://codegrepper.com/*
*://programmierfrage.com/*
*://microeducate.tech/*
*://ringingliberty.com/*
*://askandroidquestions.com/*
*://tutorialmeta.com/*
*://helpex.vn/*
*://techtalk7.com/*
*://serveanswer.com/*
*://solveforums.msomimaktaba.com/*
*://vuejscode.com/*
*://pythonshowcase.com/*
*://codeutility.org/*
*://reactquestions.com/*
*://dockerquestions.com/*
*://angularquestions.com/*
*://pythonfixing.com/*
*://stackallflow.com/*
*://nxtstage.net/*
*://intelligentsystemsmonitoring.com/*
*://localcoder.org/*
*://rotadev.com/*
*://errorsfixing.com/*
*://catwolf.org/*
*://configrouter.com/*
*://akuum.org/*
*://readforlearn.com/*
*://codehunter.cc/*
*://levitrares.com/*
*://graef.io/*
*://syntaxfix.com/*
*://ourpython.com/*
*://vigges.net/*
*://exchangetuts.com/*
*://fullstackuser.com/*
*://dtuto.com/*
*://w3coded.com/*
*://thelivingtrove.com/*
*://ti-enxame.com/*
*://desenv-web-rp-bd.com/*
*://web-dev-qa-db-pt.com/*
*://tra-loi-cau-hoi-phat-trien-web.com/*
*://suttonedfoundation.org/*
*://tousu.in/*
*://itdaan.com/*
*://itranslater.com/*
*://software-testing.com/*
*://itbaoku.cn/*
*://nibes.cn/*
*://devqanda.com/*
*://sargon24.com/*
*://javafixing.com/*
*://catchconsole.com/*
*://icopy.site/*
*://frameboxxindore.com/*
*://qa.wujigu.com/*
*://shenzhenjia.net/*
*://ogeek.cn/*
*://devdreamz.com/*
*://imtqy.com/*
*://idqna.com/*
*://peaku.co/*
*://javawenti.com/*
*://runexception.com/*
*://ebestcode.com/*
*://likecs.com/*
*://solveforum.com/*
*://codetd.com/*
*://anycodings.com/*
*://overstack.in/*
*://jonic.cn/*
*://devasking.com/*
*://askdevz.com/*
*://cans.pro/*
*://ddcode.net/*
*://w3programmers.org/*
*://faqcode4u.com/*
*://studytonight.com/*
*://chowdera.com/*
*://faqcodes.com/*
*://thecodeteacher.com/*
*://devtip.in/*
*://duoduokou.com/*
*://appsloveworld.com/*
*://learnfk.com/*
*://codingdict.com/*
*://ajaxhispano.com/*
*://ask-dev.ru/*
*://i4k.xyz/*
*://yy123.ink/*
*://icode.best/*
*://igiftidea.com/*
*://csdn.net/*
*://yocker.com/*
*://955yes.com/*
*://dovov.com/*
*://dokry.com/*
*://codefordev.com/*
*://empires-r.us/*
*://answerspoint.com/*
*://devebee.com/*
*://w3codelab.com/*
*://flvrclothing.com/*
*://pyquestions.com/*
*://djcxy.com/*
*://python.engineering/*
*://it1352.com/*
*://adoclib.com/*
*://796t.com/*
*://invalidtype.com/*
*://string.quest/*
*://winmundo.com/*
*://questu.ru/*
*://querythreads.com/*
*://super-unix.com/*
*://twblogs.net/*
*://proanswers.org/*
*://programming-articles.com/*
*://edureka.co/*
*://w3toppers.com/*
*://e-learn.cn/*
*://qandeelacademy.com/*
*://learn-codes.net/*
*://dev-answers.com/*
*://code-error.com/*
*://doraprojects.net/*
*://wikitechy.com/*
*://rateye.tistory.com/*
*://codestyle.tistory.com/*
*://tracholar.top/*
*://hellojava.com/*
*://anyabs.com/*
*://askcodes.net/*
*://python2.net/*
*://so.muouseo.com/*
*://dailydevsblog.com/*
*://stackoverflowpoint.com/*
*://developerfacts.com/*
*://copyprogramming.com/*
*://coder.gay/*
*://codejzy.com/*
*://tutorialink.com/*
*://maxinterview.com/*
*://newdevzone.com/*
*://dirask.com/*
*://im-coder.com/*
*://contactform.dev/*
*://ciupacabra.com/*
*://bildiredi.com/*
*://donolik.com/*
*://sozdizimi.com/*
*://zapytay.com/*
*://while-do.com/*
*://it-swarm.net/*
*://it-swarm.dev/*
*://it-swarm.asia/*
*://it-swarm.xyz/*
*://develop-bugs.com/*
*://android.bigresource.com/*
*://code-paper.com/*
*://howtobuildsoftware.com/*
*://ittone.ma/*
*://spec-zone.ru/*
*://techinplanet.com/*
*://javascript.tutorialink.com/*
*://issuecloser.com/*
*://dizzycoding.com/*
*://grabthiscode.com/*
*://realerlab.blogspot.com/*
*://quickanswer.blog/*
*://webdesigntips.blog/*
*://joyk.com/*
*://gushiciku.cn/*
*://truecodes.net/*
*://errorsandanswers.com/*
*://boolchr.com/*
*://itnursery.com/*
*://libsea.com/*
*://telepon.cyou/*
*://madanswer.com/*
*://programmatic.solutions/*
*://facit.edu.br/*
*://technointeract.com/*
*://saca.aussievitamin.com/*
*://stackorigin.com/*
*://solutionschecker.com/*
*://oraask.com/*
*://yeahexp.com/*
*://fullstack.cafe/*
*://ansaurus.com/*
*://mars.railpage.com.au/*
*://wikifix.dev/*
*://aing.railpage.com.au/*
*://hrefcode.com/*
*://wyzant.com/*
*://fixpython.com/*
*://stackubuntu.com/*
*://coder.horje.com/*
*://lowongan.live/*
*://pythondict.com/*
*://hsmap.xyz/*
*://pythonmana.com/*
*://ittutorialpoint.com/*
*://qastack.lk/*
*://makemeengr.com/*
*://py4u.org/*
*://snippmate.com/*
*://oursbrand.com/*
*://rowcoding.com/*
*://kausalvikash.in/*
*://pythonhowto.org/*
*://getridbug.com/*
*://developerload.com/*
*://errors-solved.com/*
*://javaerrorfix.com/*
*://thiscodeworks.com/*
*://tfetimes.com/*
*://johndeerecreditpowerplan.com/*
*://sujeshanto.blogspot.com/*
*://answersfordevelopers.blogspot.com/*
*://ingrom.com/*
*://jtuto.com/*
*://notcrash.com/*
*://blogmepost.com/*
*://developerinsider.co/*
*://coded3.com/*
*://answerbun.com/*
*://coder-solution-ru.com/*
*://sevennet-blog.tumblr.com/*
*://stklowf.blogspot.com/*
*://91r.net/*
*://manongdao.com/*
*://prograide.com/*
*://iteramos.com/*
*://resultfor.dev/*
*://heavenlymutex.com/*
*://encodingcompiler.com/*
*://technoteshelp.com/*
*://bitcoden.com/*
*://devsfeed.com/*
*://stackoverline.cyou/*
*://extends.run/*
*://copyfuture.com/*
*://sharetechnotes.com/*
*://crex24.com/*
*://yakst.com/*
*://javascriptcn.com/*
*://antworten.top/*
*://narkive.fr/*
*://narkive.com/*
*://narkive.co.il/*
*://narkive.it/*
*://narkive.no/*
*://narkive.se/*
*://narkive.dk/*
*://narkive.fi/*
*://narkive.kr/*
*://narkive.ee/*
*://narkive.pl/*
*://narkive.info.tr/*
*://narkive.hr/*
*://narkive.cz/*
*://narkive.in/*
*://niceans.com/*
*://itecnotes.com/*
*://9to5answer.com/*
*://zditect.com/*
*://boxhoidap.com/*
*://mortgagefasr860.weebly.com/*
*://folkstalk.com/*
*://angularfixing.com/*
*://splunktool.com/*
*://addcodings.com/*
*://erg.tcta.com.au/*
*://quick-advisors.com/*
*://mulloverthing.com/*
*://linuxfixes.com/*
*://forumming.com/*
*://pullrequest.ru/*
*://lmlphp.com/*
*://w3guides.com/*
```

Did not result either in uBlock adding the custom list in: moz-extension://c12c7594-a289-4459-a7ff-71d72f46dacf/dashboard.html#3p-filters.html

### Approach IV

When I "Back up to file", the custom list link is included in the backup named `my-ublock-backup_2022-11-24_11.10.00.txt` with content:

```json
{
  "timeStamp": 1669284600612,
  "version": "1.45.2",
  "userSettings": {
    "externalLists": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quenhus/uBlock-Origin-dev-filter/main/data/stackoverflow_copycats.txt",
    "importedLists": [
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quenhus/uBlock-Origin-dev-filter/main/data/stackoverflow_copycats.txt"
    ]
  },
  "selectedFilterLists": [
    "user-filters",
    "ublock-filters",
    "ublock-badware",
    "ublock-privacy",
    "ublock-quick-fixes",
    "ublock-abuse",
    "ublock-unbreak",
    "easylist",
    "easyprivacy",
    "urlhaus-1",
    "plowe-0",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quenhus/uBlock-Origin-dev-filter/main/data/stackoverflow_copycats.txt"
  ],
  "hiddenSettings": {},
  "whitelist": [
    "about-scheme",
    "chrome-extension-scheme",
    "chrome-scheme",
    "edge-scheme",
    "moz-extension-scheme",
    "opera-scheme",
    "vivaldi-scheme",
    "wyciwyg-scheme"
  ],
  "dynamicFilteringString": "behind-the-scene * * noop\nbehind-the-scene * inline-script noop\nbehind-the-scene * 1p-script noop\nbehind-the-scene * 3p-script noop\nbehind-the-scene * 3p-frame noop\nbehind-the-scene * image noop\nbehind-the-scene * 3p noop",
  "urlFilteringString": "",
  "hostnameSwitchesString": "no-large-media: behind-the-scene false\nno-csp-reports: * true",
  "userFilters": "! 2022-11-24 https://stackoverflow.com\nstackoverflow.com##.js-sticky-leftnav.left-sidebar--sticky-container\n"
}
```

So I could create a backup, then add those custom lists and "Restore from file" again. However, I do not yet know how to do that from Bash/automatically.

### Approach V

[This post](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/2986#issuecomment-333475958) explains one could add a custom filter (not a custom filter list), to Ublock0 by creating a `uBlock0@raymondhill.net.json` file with content:

```json
{
 "name": "uBlock0@raymondhill.net",
 "description": "ignored",
 "type": "storage",
 "data": {
    "adminSettings": "{\"userFilters\":\"www.test.de##script:contains(!de.test.cmsKonfig)\\n\"}"
 }
}
```

And in Windows a registry key needs to be created, whilst for Ubuntu, [this link](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/2986#issuecomment-333302591) seems to suggest the `.json` needs to be put in the `storage.managed` directory. However I have not been able to find that directory on Ubuntu 22.10, nor did I find where it should be created.

### Question

How can one add a custom blocklist to uBlock, using Bash/automatically?